# Get query param that comes before the hash with react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using react router 1.0.0, and I can't figure out if it's possible to get query params that come before the hash into my application. Here's an example of the url when I'm running my app locally:

http://127.0.0.1:8001/community/wkO_lhA_RnOMDeTA3kDgpA/calendar?coordinator=1#/cal/view/month

What I want to get is that "coordinator=1" param. All the information I've seen so far about params in react router reference getting params that come after the hash, so in the /cal/view/month portion of the URL, not before the hash.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this.props.location.query` is what you want. In your case, the vale is `{ coordinator:1 }`

For The example   http://localhost:5000/users/2?q=hello#meow . React-router loads the `User` component for this route and passes it history, location, params, route, routeParams, routes as props. Screenshot from React-Devtools for Chrome.

[image]